# Select product variations on order creation from backend - Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I found a issue with woocommerce and variable products.

The products works good on the frontend but If I try to do the same from the backend, I can't selected the variations that I want.

I just can add a meta (It's an input text field) and this is very limited.

[image]

Can I fix this with a hook/function or plugin?

Really need help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat difficult to understand. Are you asking if you can change the combination of variations for a product on the backend after an order has been made?

I have only ever been able to do such a thing, in certain situations from within fulfillment software (*ShipStation in my case*), and even then it's no simple task. The reason likely being due to the fact that WooCommerce essentially locks the order after payment, as a failsafe to the customer probably.

[image]

Comment: Hi. Yes, I want to create orders from the backend and select the variation after the payment.